# ERROR NG9 Property value does not exist on type EventTarget

Tags: angular, data-binding

I'm trying to do a data binding in Angular, but I received this error message: [ERROR] NG9: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'. [plugin angular-compiler]      src/app/data-binding/data-binding.component.html:3:42:       3 │ <input type="text" (input)="$event.target.value"/>

This is my data-binding.component.html
`

## Primeiro Componente

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="$event.target.value"/>

<h1>{{ numero }}</h1>`
```

this is my data-binding.component.ts
`import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-data-binding',
    templateUrl: './data-binding.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./data-binding.component.css']
})

export class DataBindingComponent implements OnInit {
    public numero?: number;
    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit() {}
}`
```

I tried this:

data-binding.component.html
`

## Primeiro Componente

```
<input type="text" (input)="eventHandler(($event.target as HTMLInputElement).value)">

<h1>{{ numero }}</h1>`
```

data-binding.component.ts
`import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-data-binding',
    templateUrl: './data-binding.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./data-binding.component.css']
})

export class DataBindingComponent implements OnInit {
    // Declarando a variável numero e atribuindo um valor inicial
    public numero?: number;
    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit() {}

    eventHandler(value: string): void {
        console.log('Input value:', value);
        // ... handle the value further
        this.numero = Number(value);

  }

}`
```

[ERROR] NG5002: Parser Error: Unexpected token ')' at column 55 in [eventHandler(($event.target as HTMLInputElement).value)] in D:/ProgramFiles/cursoAngular/src/app/data-binding/data-binding.component.html@2:28 [plugin angular-compiler]

```
src/app/data-binding/data-binding.component.html:5:4:
  5 │ <h1>{{ numero }}</h1>
    ╵     ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Error occurs in the template of component DataBindingComponent.

```
src/app/data-binding/data-binding.component.ts:5:15:
  5 │   templateUrl: './data-binding.component.html',
    ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

And This:

data-binding.component.html
`

## Primeiro Componente

```
<input type="text" (input)="obterNumero(value)"/>

<h1>{{ numero }}</h1>`
```

data-binding.component.ts
`import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-data-binding',
    templateUrl: './data-binding.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./data-binding.component.css']
})

export class DataBindingComponent implements OnInit {
    // Declarando a variável numero e atribuindo um valor inicial
    public numero?: number;
    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit() {}

    obterNumero(numero: number) {
        this.numero = numero;
  }

}`
```

Application bundle generation complete. [0.208 seconds]
Page reload sent to client(s).
X [ERROR] NG4: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0. [plugin angular-compiler]

```
src/app/data-binding/data-binding.component.html:3:28:
  3 │ <input type="text" (input)="obterNumero()"/>
    ╵                             ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Error occurs in the template of component DataBindingComponent.

```
src/app/data-binding/data-binding.component.ts:5:15:
  5 │   templateUrl: './data-binding.component.html',
    ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Application bundle generation failed. [0.232 seconds]
X [ERROR] NG9: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'DataBindingComponent'. [plugin angular-compiler]

```
src/app/data-binding/data-binding.component.html:3:40:
  3 │ <input type="text" (input)="obterNumero(value)"/>
    ╵                                         ~~~~~
```

Error occurs in the template of component DataBindingComponent.

```
src/app/data-binding/data-binding.component.ts:5:15:
  5 │   templateUrl: './data-binding.component.html',
    ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Application bundle generation failed. [0.207 seconds]
X [ERROR] NG9: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'DataBindingComponent'. [plugin angular-compiler]

```
src/app/data-binding/data-binding.component.html:3:40:
  3 │ <input type="text" (input)="obterNumero(value)"/>
    ╵                                         ~~~~~
```

Error occurs in the template of component DataBindingComponent.

```
src/app/data-binding/data-binding.component.ts:5:15:
  5 │   templateUrl: './data-binding.component.html',
    ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the value within your component file like the following:

**template**

```html
<input type="text" (input)="setMyNumber($event)"/>
<h1>{{ myNumber }}</h1>`
```

**component.ts**

```js
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
  myNumber!: number | undefined;

  setMyNumber(event: Event): void {
    const value = Number((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value);
    this.myNumber = value;
  }
}
```

Or like this:

**template**

```html
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myNumber"/>
<h1>{{ myNumber }}</h1>
```

**component.ts**

```js
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
   myNumber!: number | undefined;
}
```

Or using reactive forms:
**template**

```html
<input type="text" [formControl]="inputControl"/>
<pre>{{ inputControl.value | json }}</pre>
```

**component.ts**

```js
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
   inputControl = new FormControl<string | null>(null);
}
```

In this section of your code, you are getting this error because you are not providing `value` to the function `obterNumero`, you probably meant `$event` rather than `value` which is a **keyword**

```
src/app/data-binding/data-binding.component.html:3:40:
  3 │ <input type="text" (input)="obterNumero(value)"/>
```

Here, you also get an error because you are supposed to bind  `ngModel` to a variable from your component

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="$event.target.value"/>
<h1>{{ numero }}</h1>`
```

In this scenario, although the logic written is correct, `Angular` doesn't like handling that logic in the template HTML, it is better to do it on the component I showed previously. Avoid writing too much logic on the template.

```
<input type="text" 
   (input)="eventHandler(($event.target as HTMLInputElement).value)">
<h1>{{ numero }}</h1>`
```

Answer (score 0):

It works that way:

template

```
<input type="text" (input)="setMyNumber($event)"/>
<h1>{{ myNumber }}</h1>
```

component.ts

```
@Component({...})
export class DataBindingComponent {
    myNumber!: number | undefined;

    setMyNumber(event: Event): void {
        const value = Number((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value);
        this.myNumber = value;
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you mark my answer as the correct one then? Thank you